# Android Emulator can't connect to my webcam

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator

I'm having a problem in getting my webcam into my android emulator.

Below is my android avd's config.ini file

```
  avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
  abi.type=x86
  disk.dataPartition.size=200M
  hw.accelerometer=yes
  hw.audioInput=yes
  hw.battery=yes
  hw.camera.back=webcam0
  hw.camera.front=none
  hw.cpu.arch=x86
  hw.dPad=no
  hw.device.hash2=MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
  hw.device.manufacturer=Google
  hw.device.name=Galaxy Nexus
  hw.gps=yes
  hw.gpu.enabled=yes
  hw.keyboard=yes
  hw.lcd.density=320
  hw.mainKeys=no
  hw.ramSize=1024
  hw.sdCard=yes
  hw.sensors.orientation=yes
  hw.sensors.proximity=yes
  hw.trackBall=no
  image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-21\google_apis\x86\
  sdcard.size=2G
  skin.dynamic=yes
  skin.name=720x1280
  skin.path=720x1280
  tag.display=Google APIs
  tag.id=google_apis
  vm.heapSize=64
```

When I start the emulator it just switch on the webcam light for a second and show this message

```
  emulator: ERROR: cmd_camera_device_start_capturing: Device
```

and when I try to run the camera inside emulator when it is fully loaded,  it just terminate with an error message saying

```
   Camera Error
   Can't connect to the camera
```

My Laptop is Lenovo G70 with Avast Antivirus.
I update the camera driver as well.

My camera works with skype and cordova camera plugin in the browser.

**Can anyone help me? Is my camera driver block the access request by the emulator?**

Comment: can't access it either in my mac, not sure it's working at all

Comment: Did you get it to working? What's the purpose of using `emulated` camera at all :/